# Is there a way to call a API only if the url is in application.yml?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, configuration

i'm a neophyte in the field.
I'm making a simple Spring Boot application that calls a another API, edit the content and return  the data at client. So i want it to be possible to call a new API from the application only if its URL is in the configuration file (application.yml)

For example, if the application.yml is

```
custom:
  external-api:
    firstapi: http://api1.com/data/
    secondapi: https://api2.com/data
```

and if I try to create a new RequestMapping (http://api3.com/) in the code, it will not return anything or will not be possible anyway.
Is there a way?

Comment: Pls, share the code where mapping for the properties file is done.

Comment: @Justcurious I haven't implementated this code yet!

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ? @VersuS

Comment: I want, in a future, cannot to call another API if it is not in configuration file. Tell me if im not clear

Answer (score 0):

One has to design the configuration class to read the properties file in spring-boot.

```
@Value("${custom.external-api.firstapi}")
private String firstApi;
```

Read more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there is a property defined in your application.yml file

You can do  like this :

```
@Value("${custom.external-api.thirdapi:#{null}")
private String thirdApi;
```

And you will be able to check if `thirdApi` is not null

```
if(thirdApi != null){
   // call the third api
}
```